# Mongoose bulk update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to be able to update an array of objects where each object has a new unique value assigned to it.

Here is a simplified example of what I'm doing. `items` is an array of my collection items.

```
let items = [{_id: '903040349304', number: 55}, {_id: '12341244', number: 1166}, {_id: '667554', number: 51115}]
```

I want to assign a new number to each item, and then update it in collection:

```
items = items.map(item => {
  item.number = randomInt(0, 1000000);
  return item;
})
```

What would be the best way to update the collection at once? I know that I could do it in `forEach` instead of `map`, how ever this seems as a dirty way of doing it, as it won't do the bulk update.

```
items.forEach(async (item) => {
  await this.itemModel.update({_id: item._id}, {number: randomInt(0, 1000000)})
});
```

I've checked the `updateMany` as well but my understanding of it is that it's only used to update the documents with a same new value - not like in my case, that every document has a new unique value assigned to it.

Comment: Why would this be fishy, you have to change every single document, a forEach is the proper action for this.
Nontheless depending on your usecase you might want to look into middleware, with that you can inject a function when a certain action is called like update or save and change the value at that point.

Comment: Not necessarily fishy, how ever I don't think it would be a good practice to make 1000 calls to the DB while it could be done in one. I came up with a possible solution using ``bulkWrite`` - check my answer.

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of thinking, I came up with this solution using `bulkWrite`.

```
const updateQueries = [];
items.forEach(async (item) => {
  updateQueries.push({
    updateOne: {
      filter: { _id: item._id },
      update: { number: item.number },
    },
  });
});
await this.itemModel.bulkWrite(updateQueries);
```

About `bulkWrite`

> Sends multiple insertOne, updateOne, updateMany, replaceOne,
> deleteOne, and/or deleteMany operations to the MongoDB server in one
> command. This is faster than sending multiple independent operations
> (like) if you use create()) because with bulkWrite() there is only one
> round trip to MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

You can call an aggregate() to instantly update them without needing to pull them first:

Step1: get a random number with mongoDb build in `$rand` option which returns a number between 0 and 1
Step2: `$multiply` this number by 1000000 since that is what you defined ;)
Step3: use another `$set` with `$floor` to remove the decimal portion

```js
YourModel.aggregate([
  {
    '$set': {
      'value': {
        '$multiply': [
          {
            '$rand': {}
          }, 1000000
        ]
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$set': {
      'value': {
        '$floor': '$value'
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here a picture of how that looks in mongo Compass as a proof of it working:
[image]

Comment: It was a simplified question, I don't actually use random number, how ever the values are still unique and coming from an API call

Comment: Ah well that does indeed make a change in how you would solve it haha, atleast I learned about built in $rand from mongoDB by solving your question ;)

Comment: Indeed. Nevertheless, keep up the good work, you indeed learn a lot just by answering questions here :)